# calculate custom percentage per number

Tags: php

let's suppose I have a range like that

```
if amount is >=20000 USD, then percentage is 1%
if amount is >=30000 USD, then percentage is 2%
if amount is >=40000 USD, then percentage is 3%
....
```

How to calculate what is percentage for any amount I have? I actually I'm just doing if else solution (I know it's bad).

Thanks

Comment: left field approach .. if the ranges will always be be 10's of thousands. you could take the first digit of amount and minus 1

Comment: @Daenu : yes limit is 100%

Answer (score 0):

just an idea :-)

```
function convert($amount){

if ($amount < 10000){
return 0;
}else if ($amount > 100000){
return 100; //???????
}


return substr($amount,0,1)-1; //take first digit and minus 1
}
```

run it like so:

```
$a=25000;

echo convert($a).'%'; //=1%
```

Comment: neat, dont forget to take care of values that may be out of bounds

Comment: it's not working if I have amount 105500 for example. the max percentage is 100%, so a bit problem

Comment: @Zeta check again, i fixed that in an edit (demo: http://ideone.com/nwp9ni)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a condition-less approach:

```
//            |---calculate---|
max( [ min( [ floor($n/10000)-1 , 100] ) ,0] )
//                 upper bounds --^^^     ^--lower bounds
```

In plain English, divide the number by `10000`, truncate any decimals, subtract one, use `100` if more than `100`, use `0` if less than `0`.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4fce2098bec24215e14a3ae35580bf1b5537b495))

```
$numbers=[9999,11111,55555,99999,111111,666666,888888,4444444,7777777];
foreach($numbers as $n){
    echo "$n => ",max([min([floor($n/10000)-1,100]),0]),"%\n";
}
```

Output:

```
9999 => 0%
11111 => 0%
55555 => 4%
99999 => 8%
111111 => 10%
666666 => 65%
888888 => 87%
4444444 => 100%
7777777 => 100%
```